# Custom Adapter - What to do?

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I've spent all morning on this. Couldn't find a single useful solution even though I went through plenty of tuts. I'm just going to post my code.

What I want? I have an RSS Reader that grabs news from a site, stores it in a custom class. I want to create a ListView with a custom design that displays the title from every news item. This works FINE if I just use the default simple_list_view_1 from Android, but I want a custom design in the ListView.

Here's my code:

```
ArrayList<SingleNewsItem> newsList = new ArrayList<SingleNewsItem>();
```

This is the SingleNewsItem:

```
public class SingleNewsItem
{
    private String pubDate;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    private String link;

    public String getPubDate()
    {
        return pubDate;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public String getLink()
    {
        return link;
    }

    public SingleNewsItem(String _pubDate, String _title, String _description, String _link)
    {
        pubDate = _pubDate;
        description = _description;
        title = _title;
        link = _link;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Here is the Custom Adapter I tried creating:

```
public class NewsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<SingleNewsItem>>
{
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<SingleNewsItem> news;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public NewsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<SingleNewsItem> objects)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.news = objects;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        convertView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
        ArrayList item = getItem(position);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        title.setText(item.toString());

        return parent;
    }
}
```

This is my custom listview. It only has one TextView that I need for the Title:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
    android:background="#660000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

Here are the final lines:

```
myListView.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(this, R.layout.listview, newsList));
```

This doesn't work. Right now the error is in the NewsAdapter class. It says:

```
The constructor ArrayAdapter<ArrayList<SingleNewsItem>>(Context, int, ArrayList<SingleNewsItem>) is undefined
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**

The following force close error pops up after I run the app now:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams
at android.widget.ListView.measureScrapChild(ListView.java:1152)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1235)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1144)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8366)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:844)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1865)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList item = getItem(position);
```

should be

```
SingleNewsItem item = (SingleNewsItem) getItem(position);
```

And if you override the `getItem()` method to make it return a `SingleNewsItem` instead of an `Object`, you will not even have to cast it.

Then just try to save all your source files, refresh + clean your project it could be just that (that happen more often than you can think).

**EDIT**
Also your code is not optimized, because the `getView()` method can be called multiple times even for a View that had already been created, if you scroll the ListView for example.
So your should first test if your convertView is null or not:

```
SingleNewsItem item = getItem(position); //You should override this method
TextView tv;

if (convertView != null) { //View already created
    tv = (TextView) convertView.getTag();
}
else { //View already created
    convertView = this.inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);
    tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    convertView.setTag(tv);
}

tv.setText(item.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks! I did that. Solved the error in code but when I run it, it force closes. I've edited my question with the log info. Please check.

Comment: I think it's because the root layout of your listview.xml file is a RelativeLayout and not a LinearLayout. I really don't know if it matters or not but I don't see anything else...

Comment: Does it have something to do with using the Inflater and setting certain parameters? I'm really new to this :s

Comment: No I don't tink parameters matters because I already did custom adapters several times and it worked, the only thing is that I always used LinearLayout a the root element. Did you try it ?

Comment: Can you provide me with code for such an adapter? I want to be able to display one image and one textview in it. It would help me greatly.

Comment: The commented lines are the ones that don't work (that utilize my custom adapter). Can you check if something is wrong with them?

int layoutID = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
//int layoutID = R.layout.listview;
ArrayAdapter<SingleNewsItem> aaNews = new ArrayAdapter<SingleNewsItem>(this, layoutID, newsList);
myListView.setAdapter(new NewsAdapter(this, R.layout.listview, newsList));
   myListView.setAdapter(aaNews);

Comment: Damn that's messy. Hope you can decipher it :)

Comment: Lines 2, 3 & 5 are useless. You are creating an adapter that you shouldn't use because you have your custom one.

Comment: Lines 3 and 5 are the ones that I'm temporarily using (for using Android's built-in simple_list_view_1.

The lines that are commented are the ones that are for MY adapter. Since its not working, I commented them.